Firebase ID token has incorrect \"aud\" (audience) claim. Expected XXX but got XXX
I'm creating app with React Native and nodeJS. I already have my auth system. Now I try to implement Google Sign In. So :

Created a Google application in Firebase.
Generated the .keystore file and obtained the SHA1 key.
Updated the build.gradle to install the SDK on the client.
Placed the file in the client and the Google service file in my Node.js app.
Implemented the code in React Native and Node.js.
Retrieved the token from the client.
Encountered an error while testing with Postman.

I get this error testing on Postman :

Message : "Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim.
Expected "tak-muscu" but got
"XXXX-ruib6t1s7lochabens3f3ep67pa411nc.apps.googleusercontent.com".
Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the
service account used to authenticate this SDK. See
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for
details on how to retrieve an ID token."

I get the token from my client :
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId: 'XXXXX-ruib6t1s7lochabens3f3ep67pa411nc.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    androidClientId: 'XXXXX-fvv7nndd0q53hvoht9cldt82jm5a9306.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scopes: ['profile', 'email']
  });


  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const idToken = userInfo.idToken;
      console.log('ID Token:', idToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Google Sign-In error', error.message);
    }
  };

I Pass it to the route with Postman :
router.post('/google-signin', async (req, res) => {
    const { idToken } = req.body;
    const result = await verifyGoogleToken(idToken);
    if (result.status === 'success') {
      res.send({ message: 'Authentication successful', user: result.decodedToken });
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({ message: 'Authentication failed', error: result.message });
    }
  });

Function verifyGoogleToken :
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const verifyGoogleToken = async (idToken) => {
  try {
    const decodedToken = await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    console.log("Token validé avec succès", decodedToken);
    return { status: 'success', uid: decodedToken.uid };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur lors de la vérification du token', error);
    return { status: 'error', message: error.message };
  }
};
module.exports = { verifyGoogleToken };

App.js server :
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./secrets/service-account-file.json'); 

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  });

I tried it 4 times... and I get the same error every time

I don't see any details on how exactly you are passing the token to the route.  You could be doing something wrong but we can't see what that might be.  Please edit the question to provide complete instructions on how anyone can reproduce all the steps needed to generate the error.

The problem is that I was not using the correct Token. I was using the google sign in token instead of the firebase token. So when I pass my token in the server, I get this error.
So, here the solution I found :
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'; //import this
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
        
const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn(); // here you get Google Sign in token
    
const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
const userCredential = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential); // use google sign in token for auth to Firebase
const firebaseIdToken = await userCredential.user.getIdToken(true);
console.log('Firebase ID Token:', firebaseIdToken); // Use this token for server.

You can then pass firebaseIdToken to your server

This is the right way:
At React Native Frontend -
// Starting File
 useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId:
        "Your Key Here",
    });
  }, []);

// Other file
import { GoogleSignin } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";

const signIn = async () => {
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    await GoogleSignin.signOut();

    const response = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    if (isSuccessResponse(response)) {
      const idToken = response.data.idToken;

      // Sending idToken to backend
      const res = await apiClient.post(GOOGLE_LOGIN_ROUTE, { idToken });


    } 
};


At Express.js/Node.js Backend -
Use "google-auth-library" and Do not use 'firebase-admin'
import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";
const client = new OAuth2Client(
  "Same webClientId used in the frontend"
);

export const googleLogin = async (request, response) => {

    const { idToken } = request.body;

    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken,
      audience:
        "Same webClientId used in the frontend put here again ", 
    });

    const googleUser = ticket.getPayload();

    const { email, name } = googleUser;
    }

Use the same webClientId in all the 3 places which is provided by Firebase in the google-services.json file
